# Blocking FORWARD on iptables except port 80

Tags: iptables

I got a subnet that is protected by a computer that acts as a firewall. The rules I want this firewall to have are:

Deny all INPUT

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

Allow all OUTPUT

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
```

Route all packets FROM the subnet to the outside

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Drop all packets from the outside to the subnet
???

Route packets to port 80 to a server in the subnet

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.2.143 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 172.16.32.131
```

The firewall's IP on eth0 is 192.168.2.143 and on eth1 is 172.16.32.254 and the server is 172.16.32.131

The subnet is 172.16.32.0/24

I got everything working except that it routes all packets from the outside to the subnet and not only those to the web server. How do I prevent this?

Comment: First of all avoid catch-all rules and set the default policy if possible. For example, instead of adding a last catch-all rule like `-A INPUT -j DROP`, set the policy to be DROP by default with `-P INPUT DROP` so that anything that doesn't match a rule gets dropped.

Comment: Welcome in Security SE. While this question is somewhat related to security as being about firewalling, it is very specific to Linux's IPTables configuration and should therefore be more suited on the [unix.se] site.

Comment: Just reading your title  you can have the general policy for FORWARD as DROP, and the  exception, the one it allows, as ALLOW.  I don't know if that helps.. You may already know that.

Answer (score 2):

The default policy is to accept packets that do not match any rule. To change this, use:

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

You can check the current rule set with `iptables -L`. See also http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html (the policy feature is mentioned on the bottom).